# Solidity to ZoKrates DSL?

Tags: zokrates

I know this might sound out of the ordinary or kind of naive , but what are the potential challenges and considerations of translating Solidity code to ZoKrates DSL for zero-knowledge proof implementation ?

What is preventing developers to design a tool that automatically converts Solidity to ZoKrates DSL, which later can be compiled in ZoKrates ?